# Azure linked service using python

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service

I have created a Linked service in azure data factory using azure portal. I want to connect to this Linked service in notebook activity in synapse using python. Do we have any such api?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried and your expected output?

Comment: @Bhavani...As I could not find anything to retrieve the Linked Service in Notebook, that is why I asked this question here. What are the ways we can do that. What I am trying is, I am calling web API from Notebook, get the response, encrypt the response and store into Blob Storage. As I am using Managed VNet, so I can't connect to Blob storage directly, that is why I need the Linked Service(which I already created through Azure Portal) programmatically. Please let me know if you need any more detail

Comment: Did you follow any approach for this?

Comment: @Bhavani... I did not find anything so far. The only thing I can think of using Python TokenLibrary, but that is also not fulfilling my purpose completely. Can you please guide on this if you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements you can directly copy data from synapse notebook to your Azure blob storage using python itself without creating linked service in data factory.
I created Azure blob storage and created new container and generated SAS for the blob storage.

[image]

I am have created data frame in synapse notebook using python using below code:

import pandas as pd

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
'Name': ['ABC', 'CDE', 'BBA', 'DSA'],
'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
'Gender': ['F', 'M', 'M', 'M']

}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to save the dataframe as csv file in azure blob storage for that I converted the dataframe to csv format using below code:

```
csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
```

I copied the connection string of blob storage account.

[image]

I copied the data into blob storage using below code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

connection_string = "<connection string>"
container_name = "<container name>"
blob_name = "<filename>.csv"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

blob_client.upload_blob(csv_data, overwrite=True)
```

It executed successfully.

[image]

My file is created in blob storage container successfully.

[image]

Comment: @Bhavani..thank you for the detailed information. I need to connect to the linked service to make a REST call to outside network api. As I am using managed Vnet, the direct rest call fails, so need to get the linked service in notebook and fire the REST call get the data, encrypt it and then store in blob. In this entire thing the only part I am trying to figure out to get the already created Linked service into notebook to make the REST call

Comment: If you want to access adls or blob service linked service from notebook you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python).